# PHP: Downloading *.tar.gz file increases file size and changes MD5

Tags: php, http-headers, md5

I need to offer downloadable *.tar.gz files on a website. For each file, I pre-generated MD5 checksums (and present them alongside the download links, for checking after the download). However, both the file size and the MD5 checksum change after a file was downloaded.

I use the following PHP headers etc.:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Pragma: public");
ob_clean();
readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

When downloading the file directly using `curl`, I get:

```
file size: 440875
MD5: f03a0995aec6f2f5f8810b635a6829b8
```

which is correct!

However, when downloading from the website, I get:

```
file size: 2488320
MD5: 953db14625c978e387540b6742121309
```

which is the problem!

What can I do to change this?

Comment: Can you check real request & response headers from your browser? Also, what's with other filetypes, like *.jpg or *.rar?

Comment: I checked, and it seems to be a browser-specific problem. On further research, I found that Safari (the browser I used to test this first) has problems with some file transfers (apparently also for my problem), while on other browsers, e.g. Chrome or Firefox, I do not have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Safari when I encountered this problem. Using other browsers (Chrome and Firefox), my php headers performed as expected.

On further research I found that Safari is bound to such problems. Here, I was using a php redirect to the *.tar.gz file I provide for download. Using the direct path link to the file did not cause any problems. Only under Safari the file is downloaded and apparently "unzipped" automatically, i.e. removing the .gz extension and creating a larger downloaded file (where MD5 is of course different).

I am a bit disappointed that all other browsers I tested do the right thing, while only Safari has this problem.

Comment: At least Safari removes the archive's file extension after uncompressing the file. When I tried to download compressed file in Chrome (on my macbook), it downloaded and uncompressed it, but did not remove the extension. I was breaking my head why I couldn't open it with tar, gzip, gunzip, until finally decided to check its size and open with a text editor, and realized that it's actually uncompressed but still has the extension in the filename. Hell knows why this happens